# first directive: a crude, first order estimate?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-request

Here is an interesting sentence from Spectroscopy for Amateur Astronomers by Trypsteen and Walker (pg 30):

> Of course, other factors, such as the slit width, telescope parameters ... influence the theoretical calculated value of R. Nevertheless, the value of R, calculated this way, gives a **first directive** of the achievable performance. [<sub>(Source)</sub>](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Spectroscopy_for_Amateur_Astronomers/DNAoDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22calculated%20this%20way,%20gives%20a%22%20%22the%20achievable%20performance%22&pg=PA30&printsec=frontcover)

Context: R refers to the resolving power. The 'way' the author refers to is a simple calculation that *only* takes into account of the dispersion and base length of the prism.

I suppose "first directive" here means a crude estimate (first order estimate, a hint) of the achievable performance?

Comment: Possibly typographical error for 'first derivative', especially if the book is an OCR version. You should always mention the source. Don't make us do your search for you.

Comment: @Michael Harvey sure, I'll add it right away, and sorry for the inconvenience! It's not OCR by the way.

Comment: I would say "first order indication". It is interesting that "directive" is a synonym for a different meaning of the word "order"; it makes me wonder whether a computer has been involved in editing.

Comment: @Peter - Possibly a translation error. [Trypsteen](https://be.linkedin.com/in/marc-trypsteen-93183832) is Belgian; I have a feeling that despite his English sounding name, [Richard Walker](https://www.ursusmajor.ch/astrospektroskopie/richard-walkers-page/index.html) is German-speaking Swiss.

Comment: It's not a common usage, but a "directive" here is "that which directs" - a ***first directive*** = ***rough guide***.

Comment: I believe the author means "first approximation" and something simply went amiss.  @FumbleFingers: Where have you seen that usage?

Comment: @cruthers: Like I said, it's not a common usage. My "that which directs" definition is from the full OED (but marked as "obsolete"). Most usages of "first directive" tend to mean either an early prototype or the most important ***directive = instruction = rule***, so it wouldn't be easy for me to find another matching OP's example, if they even exist at all in Google Books. It may be influenced by translation from a related German form, but I don't have a big problem with *first directive = initial pointer to **something like** the true value which is to be established later*.

Comment: In German, one meaning of 'Direktive' is 'guideline', so maybe this is a _falsche Freunde_ or 'false friend' issue.